# What does having a class selector do when appended to an event type on a listener?

Tags: jquery

I've seen this and I don't understand what the class selector does on the event type:

```
$("#Selector").on("click.image", function() { . . . });
// ---------------------^----^ this guy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a class selector, it's an "[event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)," which is a jQuery concept. It groups handlers for an event so you can act on the group later. For instance, it lets you do this:

```
$("#Selector").off("click.image");
```

...and only remove the `click` handlers that were hooked up using that namespace, not others.

This is particularly useful in plugins and such when you need to be sure not to obstruct other things going on with the elements, but it's useful in non-plugin code as well (for much the same reason).

Answer (score 1):

It's called namespacing. It's useful when adding and removing specific events at any given time.

Here is more info: http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/